# Using document.body.appendChild to append a whole code block?

Tags: javascript, appendchild

Is it possible to append a whole code block using appendChild? This is what I want to append:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="some.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles-ie.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="85d6d1c5f8f9c87ae016eae0ee6994c7.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

I guess I cant append it using appendChild?

Comment: Why would you append it into the `<body>`? Shouldn't it go into the `<head>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using pure JavaScript, you could use this:

```
var body = document.body;
body.innerHTML += 'Whatever you want to append.';
```

Comment: Psst: `document.body`

Answer (score 0):

```
function addLABjs(callback) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("src", "YourOtherScript.js");
    script.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }, false);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

// the guts of this userscript


function main() {
    $LAB.script("YourOtherScript.js").wait()
        .script("YourOtherScript.js")
        .script("YourOtherScript.js").wait();

    $(document).ready(function () {
    });
}

addLABjs(main);
```